# Pear tree leaves

Tags: fruit-trees, pear

Planted in the ground, this is the 4th yea. With the beginning of spit was healthy and lots of blooms.
Suddenly some leaves started becoming black.
Any idea why?
Thank you

Comment: are you able to edit this post, provide more details and a picture to be able to help more?

Comment: Sounds like Black Spot, a soil fungus that harms pear, apple, and rose leaves. Spray with natural or chemical fungicides.